# Alias a type to be specialised later

Tags: python, python-typing, python-3.12

(Using python 3.12, so the `type` syntax is available to me.)

During testing, I might abuse types (the examples here are contrived. In real life, I am using a custom class subclassing lists, and I would like to give a list instead of the subclass while testing using pydantic validators to avoid a lot of boilerplate)

With non-specialisable types, this is easy and typing is happy:

```py
if TYPE_CHECKING:
    type MyNumber = int | float
else:
    type MyNumber = int


class TstBase:
    a: MyNumber

print(TstBase(a=1.2))
```

But when using specialisable types:

```py
if TYPE_CHECKING:
    type MyContainer = list | set
else:
    type MyContainer = list


class TstContainer(BaseModel):
    a: MyContainer[str] # ERROR HERE
```

There pyright complains with

> Type "list[Unknown]" is already specialized

> Type "set[Unknown]" is already specialized

How Can I tell pyright that `MyContainer` will be specialised later? .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obvious once the answer is known:

```py
if TYPE_CHECKING:
    type MyContainer[T] = list[T] | set[T]
else:
    type MyContainer[T] = list[T]


class TstContainer(BaseModel):
    a: MyContainer[str] # no error!
```